# Apache rewrite rule for nginx

Tags: apache-http-server, nginx

I have to create a rewrite rule for apache, as well as for nginx.

Required change:

```
/search?q=test&**p**=1 to /search?q=test&**page**=1
```

For Apache, the code below works well but I can't convert it for nginx.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)&p=([0-9]+)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(search/?)$ /search?q=%1&page=%2 [NC,L,R]
```

I have tried something like this:

```
  if ($query_string ~ "^q=(.*)&p=([0-9]+)(.*)$"){
    rewrite ^/(search/?)$ /search?q=%1&page=%2 redirect;
  }
```

But it ends with something like that:

```
/search?q=%1&page=%2&q=%1&page=%2&q=%1&page=%2&q=%1&page=%2&q
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[Nginx documentation on module rewrite](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) has some examples. Essentially you're using the wrong character to identify the regular expression results. It should be `$` rather than `%`.

You might also have to repeat your regular expression for the matching int he rewrite rule.